# Why does drop and create synonym constantly repeat

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

```
DECLARE @synName VARCHAR(100), @synTarget VARCHAR(150), @synSchemaName VARCHAR (110)

DECLARE Syns CURSOR FOR
   SELECT 
      s.name, base_object_name, sc.name AS synSchemaName
   FROM 
      sys.synonyms s
   INNER JOIN 
      sys.schemas sc ON s.schema_id = sc.schema_id
   WHERE 
      s.name in ('test1') 

   OPEN Syns
   FETCH NEXT FROM Syns INTO @synName, @synTarget, @synSchemaName

   WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS <> -1
   BEGIN
      PRINT 'DROP SYNONYM guest.' + @synName
      EXEC ('DROP SYNONYM guest.' + @synName) 

      SET @synTarget = CASE 
                          WHEN @synTarget LIKE '%test2%' THEN REPLACE(@synTarget,'[test2]','[test3]')
                          WHEN @synTarget LIKE '%test3%' THEN REPLACE(@synTarget,'[test3]','[test4]')
                          WHEN @synTarget LIKE '%test4%' THEN REPLACE(@synTarget,'[test4]','[test2]')
                       END

     PRINT 'CREATE SYNONYM guest.' + @synName + ' FOR ' +@synTarget
     EXEC ('CREATE SYNONYM guest.' + @synName + ' FOR ' +@synTarget)

     PRINT 'TRUNCATE TABLE'+@syntarget
     --EXEC ('TRUNCATE TABLE'+@syntarget)

     FETCH NEXT FROM Syns INTO @synName, @synTarget, @synSchemaName
  END

  CLOSE Syns
  DEALLOCATE Syns
```

I am working with the above code that I have in another post. I ran into a new issue after running the query. Instead of it just doing this once.

```
DROP SYNONYM guest.test1
CREATE SYNONYM guest.test1 FOR [master].[dbo].[test4]
TRUNCATE TABLE[master].[dbo].[test4]
```

It will do this instead

```
DROP SYNONYM guest.test1
CREATE SYNONYM guest.test1 FOR [master].[dbo].[test4]
TRUNCATE TABLE[master].[dbo].[test4]

DROP SYNONYM guest.test1
CREATE SYNONYM guest.test1 FOR [master].[dbo].[test2]
TRUNCATE TABLE[master].[dbo].[test2]

DROP SYNONYM guest.test1
CREATE SYNONYM guest.test1 FOR [master].[dbo].[test3]
TRUNCATE TABLE[master].[dbo].[test3]

DROP SYNONYM guest.test1
CREATE SYNONYM guest.test1 FOR [master].[dbo].[test4]
TRUNCATE TABLE[master].[dbo].[test4]

DROP SYNONYM guest.test1
CREATE SYNONYM guest.test1 FOR [master].[dbo].[test2]
TRUNCATE TABLE[master].[dbo].[test2]

DROP SYNONYM guest.test1
CREATE SYNONYM guest.test1 FOR [master].[dbo].[test3]
TRUNCATE TABLE[master].[dbo].[test3]

DROP SYNONYM guest.test1
CREATE SYNONYM guest.test1 FOR [master].[dbo].[test4]
TRUNCATE TABLE[master].[dbo].[test4]

DROP SYNONYM guest.test1
CREATE SYNONYM guest.test1 FOR [master].[dbo].[test2]
TRUNCATE TABLE[master].[dbo].[test2]

DROP SYNONYM guest.test1
CREATE SYNONYM guest.test1 FOR [master].[dbo].[test3]
TRUNCATE TABLE[master].[dbo].[test3]

DROP SYNONYM guest.test1
CREATE SYNONYM guest.test1 FOR [master].[dbo].[test4]
TRUNCATE TABLE[master].[dbo].[test4]

DROP SYNONYM guest.test1
CREATE SYNONYM guest.test1 FOR [master].[dbo].[test2]
TRUNCATE TABLE[master].[dbo].[test2]

DROP SYNONYM guest.test1
CREATE SYNONYM guest.test1 FOR [master].[dbo].[test3]
TRUNCATE TABLE[master].[dbo].[test3]

DROP SYNONYM guest.test1
CREATE SYNONYM guest.test1 FOR [master].[dbo].[test4]
TRUNCATE TABLE[master].[dbo].[test4]

DROP SYNONYM guest.test1
CREATE SYNONYM guest.test1 FOR [master].[dbo].[test2]
TRUNCATE TABLE[master].[dbo].[test2]

DROP SYNONYM guest.test1
CREATE SYNONYM guest.test1 FOR [master].[dbo].[test3]
TRUNCATE TABLE[master].[dbo].[test3]

DROP SYNONYM guest.test1
CREATE SYNONYM guest.test1 FOR [master].[dbo].[test4]
TRUNCATE TABLE[master].[dbo].[test4]

DROP SYNONYM guest.test1
CREATE SYNONYM guest.test1 FOR [master].[dbo].[test2]
TRUNCATE TABLE[master].[dbo].[test2]

DROP SYNONYM guest.test1
CREATE SYNONYM guest.test1 FOR [master].[dbo].[test3]
TRUNCATE TABLE[master].[dbo].[test3]

DROP SYNONYM guest.test1
CREATE SYNONYM guest.test1 FOR [master].[dbo].[test4]
TRUNCATE TABLE[master].[dbo].[test4]

DROP SYNONYM guest.test1
CREATE SYNONYM guest.test1 FOR [master].[dbo].[test2]
TRUNCATE TABLE[master].[dbo].[test2]

DROP SYNONYM guest.test1
CREATE SYNONYM guest.test1 FOR [master].[dbo].[test3]
TRUNCATE TABLE[master].[dbo].[test3]

DROP SYNONYM guest.test1
CREATE SYNONYM guest.test1 FOR [master].[dbo].[test4]
TRUNCATE TABLE[master].[dbo].[test4]
..... and so on ......
```

When I take out both the `EXEC` commands from the drop and create it only shows once. But nothing is actually being done. When I use the `EXEC` for the DROP only and comment out the other ones it drops the synonym and shows it once. But once I include the `EXEC` for the create it starts repeating like crazy and clears all the tables.

I have removed the braces around test2 and everything to see if that works and am still having the same issue.

I am lost on why it does this and how to fix it so it only goes through one time and then stops.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The changes you are doing in the loop affect the system views your cursor is reading. Your cursor also "sees", and reflects, them. This is the default behaviour, which can be changed by the `STATIC` option:

```
DECLARE Syns CURSOR STATIC FOR
   SELECT
   ...
```

The `STATIC` option in a cursor declaration causes the cursor to create and use a temporary copy of the data obtained from the underlying tables/views. This way any changes to those datasets will not be not reflected in the cursor.

More information about this and other cursor options can be found in the manual page:

- [DECLARE CURSOR (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180169.aspx)

Comment: this fixed what i needed to do. I changed it to look like what you have but added `DECLARE Syns CURSOR LOCAL STATIC FOR
SELECT`

Comment: Yes, `LOCAL` makes perfect sense here. In most cases (I believe, in yours too) it also make sense to use `FORWARD_ONLY READ_ONLY` (in addition to `LOCAL STATIC`) – that makes the cursor still lighter on resource usage.